# unable to get property 'getSouthWest' of undefined or null reference

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I do all my development on Chrome, and today decided to open up the dreaded IE to see how things look there. I stumbled upon a problem with my Geolocation code. I have to get the `getSouthWest` and `getNorthEast` bounds for the location and this is done via the following code, inside a function called `codeLatLng()`:

```
if (results[0]) {
    split1 = results[0].formatted_address.split(', ');
    var swlat = results[0].geometry.bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
    var swlng = results[0].geometry.bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
    var nelat = results[0].geometry.bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
    var nelng = results[0].geometry.bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
});
```

The console error appeared on IE:

> 'Unable to get property '*getSouthWest' of undefined or null reference*'.

After a little digging, I changed the results reference from results[0] to results[1], and this works great. However, the error has left me a little nervous going forward that my script may break again, if bounds aren't found for results[1].

Is there a more efficient, built-in way of getting the bounds when using geolocation? I am also obtaining the latitude and longitude when geolocating, via the following code:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
}
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng);
}
var geocoder1 = new google.maps.Geocoder();
function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder1.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        // I have a bunch of code here that creates hidden
        // input fields with the lat, lng, swlat, swlng, nelat and nelng
        });
    });
});
```

I know that with Places, I can use the following code:

```
swlat = place.geometry.viewport.getSouthWest().lat();
// etc for swlng, nelat & nelng
```

so can I for example use something similar inside `successFunction()`? I have looked around and tried a few things:

1) I added a new `var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();` under `var latlng` and then changed the `var swlat` to:

```
var swlat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
```

but this returned a latitude of 180.

2) I changed `var bounds` in 1) above to `var bounds = map.getBounds();`, but this gave me the bounds for the whole of the UK!

I'm really scratching my head now. Can anyone guide me to the solution? I've read into HTML Geolocation and apparently such a thing as `position.coords.southwest.latitude` isn't defined, which is a shame.

the only other thing that I can think of would be to iterate through the results, starting with results[0], until we find a set of bounds for the geolocation. But this seems a lot of work, it would be nice if there a bounds readily available for the geolocation, just as there is a lat and lng.

Any help much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I tried to use the code :

```
var bounds = map.getBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(latlng, latlng));
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
```

It seemed a great idea but what's being returned is the bounds for the whole of the UK, again. One day soon I'll get there!

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee for a returned `bounds`-property.

e.g. when the `location_type` is ROOFTOP , the result is an exact match(a coordinate) .

bounds usually will be returned for streets and areas like countries, states etc.

When no bounds will be returned you may either set all variables to the returned location or use the `viewport`-property(it's a `LatLngBounds`-object too)

Comment: I'm using the viewport to get the swlat-nelng via the Places api for autocomplete, and it suits me fine. I'll do some coding to try to get this into my hidden fields when I do geolocation. Hope you don't mind me touching base if I have a question. If no bounds or viewport are found, then I can simply build a custom viewport with a 1 mile buffer from the returned latitude and longitude. I do this with autocomplete and works great. Let me do some coding...

Comment: of course you may simply add some margin, but what's the final goal? For example, I live in a very small street(maybe 80 meters long), when I add a margin of 1 mile the result wouldn't be desirable.

Comment: sure, the final goal is to locate suppliers within x-miles of the boundary entered. So it's in fact undesirable to have too small a search boundary as it then limits the results.

Comment: little question, currently I have `var swlng = results[1].geometry.bounds.getSouthWest().lng();`, so are you proposing that I change it to `var swlng = results[1].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest().lng();`, or is there a better solution? If there is, tell me I need to look further because I've been sat here for an hour now scratching my head. Thanks.

Comment: when there are no bounds I would request the data based on a radius starting at the location.

Comment: unfortunately my experience of the maps api is so poor. i'm going to have to outsource this. 3 hours at my computer getting nowhere. there is a better solution, I can feel it. Just don't know how I should be using calling for `LatLngBounds`.